# How to see only changing register after each instruction in Spike?

Tags: bare-metal, spike

I am using spike bare metal mode to run the compiled code for RISC-V. I want to see or save (in a text file) the register only which is changed after each instruction. Is it possible to do it and how?
If it is not possible, how can I save all the registers (in a text file) after each instruction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I searched I found the answer on the main GitHub page in issues section. It is answered [in this question](https://github.com/riscv-software-src/riscv-isa-sim/issues/579).
It is needed to build the spike by using the `--enable-commitlog` flag ***in older versions***. Also, it is needed to run the spike with the `--log-commits` flag.

Comment: spike doesn't need  `--enable-commitlog` on new versions. The releted merge is here https://github.com/riscv-software-src/riscv-isa-sim/pull/1189